# How to place a component to a specific place in parent component structure in Angular 9?

Tags: html, css, angular

For example ,
In Component c html:

```
<a>
  <b></b>
<a/>
```

In Component a html , how to specify where to place component b? like in Component a html:

```
<div>
  <lable>Title</lable>
  <div>'this is the place where I want to place b'</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In component b.ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html'
})
```

- you can see the selector of name app-b
- you can use this selector in component a

```
<div>
  <lable>Title</lable>
  <app-b></app-b>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , maybe the question not that clear. In my case ,  component a&b are independent and I could not place b in a in advance , that's why I do it in component c and place b within a . The question is how to pre-reserve a specific place for the b in a.

Comment: Now I understand your problem but you can't do that in angular.

Comment: but you can add seperately in c like that first line <a></a>  second line <b></b>

Comment: Ops.. the reason I do this is I want to use some pre-defined styles in a and apply them to b , you can take a as a toolbar component and b is a button or other related thing...
Thanks , I'll try it in other way.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can do this with content projection.. <ng-content>